# non-nullable instance field '_number' must be initialized. (documentation) try adding an initializer expression,

Tags: flutter, dart

> non-nullable instance field '_number' must be initialized. (documentation) try adding an initializer expression

i have been trying to use UserModels and I added late to the constructors. why am I having red error?

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code or other text. Use the [edit] link in the question and paste the text into it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you have to deal with in this case when dealing with null-safety.

1. `snapshot.data()` can be `null` so you can't access its `[ID]` value unconditionally.
2. `snapshot.data()?[ID]` can also be `null` so you can't unconditionally assign it's value to a non-nullable variable.

First you must use the null-aware operator `?` : `snapshot.data()?[ID]`

Then you can either transform your variables into `nullable` `String?`.

Or: Give a **fallback** value in case `snapshot.data()?[ID]` is null using `??` :

`_id = snapshot.data()?[ID] ?? 'fallback';`